# Facing issue in Json parsing user profile feed

Tags: android, json, parsing

> I am working on a project in which I have to parse user feed data
>   using Json.

Here is the url of json:

```
http://ourfield.affixwebsolution.com/api/feed?data={%22userId%22:210}
```

> This is my code where I am parsing the json

```
 public static ArrayList<FeedDataClass> parseFeedddata(String res)
    {
        ArrayList<FeedDataClass>arr =new ArrayList<FeedDataClass>();
        FeedDataClass obj=new FeedDataClass();
           JSONArray jsonArray ;
           JSONObject jsonInnerObj = null;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(res);

             jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");    
             Log.d("eaweaer", jsonArray.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                  jsonInnerObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                  try {
                      obj.strid = jsonInnerObj.getString("id");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }


                try {
                    JSONObject timeline = new JSONObject(jsonInnerObj.getJSONObject("timeline").toString());
                    obj.strusername=timeline.getString("username");
                    Log.d("efe", obj.strusername);
                    obj.strurl=timeline.getString("avatar_url");
                    Log.d("aeefwe", obj.strurl);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                try {
                    obj.strtext=jsonInnerObj.getString("text");
                    Log.d("qeeqf", obj.strtext);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                arr.add(obj);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

> now the problem is, there are total three posts in json, but everytime
>   I am getting last feed . also it is getting printed 3 times in UI
>   because loop is running perfectly. dont know what is the mistake I am
>   doing here.

Help me to sort out this issue, Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one instance of `obj` which keeps on updating the same memory location. In the final loop cycle it gets updated with 3rd value and shows you. But yes you add it 3 times in the list so you have same object thrice.

Move

```
FeedDataClass obj=new FeedDataClass();
JSONObject jsonInnerObj = null;
```

inside `for` loop.

Comment: but, It gives perfect result in log cat. but when I add obj to arr and try to display the value in UI, at that time it returns the same value three times. but at the parsing time, Log.d prints all the three value... :(